# Rust: return immutable borrow after modifying

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

In Rust I am trying to update a cache and then return the result.

```
fn cached_res(&mut self) -> &Vec<u64> {
  if self.last_update.elapsed() >= REFRESH_RATE {
    self.a = do_something(...);
  }
  return &self.a;
}

fn use_cached_res(&mut self) {
  let b = self.cached_res();
  b.iter().map(|x| x + 1).collect()
}
```

And the compilation fails due to

```
173 |         let b = cached_res(self);
    |                            ---- mutable borrow occurs here
...
179 |                 .map(|f| self.do_something(&f))
    |                  --- ^^^ ---- second borrow occurs due to use of `*self` in closure
    |                  |   |
    |                  |   immutable borrow occurs here
    |                  mutable borrow later used by call
```

I *think* I understand why it fails and a possible workaround could be to have a method that only updates the cache and another that returns the result so in that way the mutable borrow is dropped and b is not borrowed as mutable.

```
fn refresh(&mut self) {
  if self.last_update.elapsed() >= REFRESH_RATE {
    self.a = do_something(...);
  }
}
fn res(&self) -> &Vec<u64> {
  &self.a
}
fn use_cached_res(&mut self) {
  self.refresh();
  let b = self.res();
  b.iter().map(|x| x + 1).collect()
}
```

However, I would like to have these constraints defined in `cached_res` so that downstream users don't have to use such methods in the right sequence. IIUC what I want is that `cached_res` returns an immutable borrow of self after having modified self.

Please let me know if there is additional information or clarifications that I can provide.

Comment: One workaround could be to use interior mutability. Generally internal caches are exposed to the "outside world" through shared references, because mutating the state of a cache is not a meaningful observable change, it's just for the sake of performance. See e.g. [moka](https://docs.rs/moka/latest/moka/future/struct.Cache.html#method.insert).

Comment: IIUC for this case then RefCell<T> could be as a possible candidate, right? The code is single threaded at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve it is with interior mutability using [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html):

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::ops::Deref;
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};

const REFRESH_RATE: Duration = Duration::from_millis(16);

pub struct A {
    a: RefCell<Vec<u64>>,
    last_update: Instant,
}

impl A {
    fn cached_res(&self) -> impl Deref<Target = Vec<u64>> + '_ {
        if self.last_update.elapsed() >= REFRESH_RATE {
            *self.a.borrow_mut() = Vec::new();
        }
        self.a.borrow()
    }

    pub fn use_cached_res(&self) -> Vec<u64> {
        let b = self.cached_res();
        b.iter().map(|&x| self.process(x)).collect()
    }

    fn process(&self, _x: u64) -> u64 {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

This has some extra overhead to keep track of borrows at runtime, but will give you the most flexibility and would even allow you to return `impl DerefMut` if you like. You can easily translate this to `RwLock` (`borrow_mut` -> `write` and `borrow` -> `read`) or `Mutex` (`lock`) if you need this struct to be `Sync`.

Another way is to invert the control flow by taking a closure:

```rust
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};

const REFRESH_RATE: Duration = Duration::from_millis(16);

pub struct A {
    a: Vec<u64>,
    last_update: Instant,
}

impl A {
    fn cached_res<F, R>(&mut self, f: F) -> R
    where
        F: FnOnce(&Self, &Vec<u64>) -> R,
    {
        if self.last_update.elapsed() >= REFRESH_RATE {
            self.a = Vec::new();
        }
        f(self, &self.a)
    }

    pub fn use_cached_res(&mut self) -> Vec<u64> {
        self.cached_res(|self_, b| b.iter().map(|&x| self_.process(x)).collect())
    }

    fn process(&self, _x: u64) -> u64 {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

This puts constraints on how you can use `cached_res` but doesn't require changing your struct or introducing overhead.